# How to get the values from multiple dynaforms?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-extensions, dynamicform

I have been following this tutorial

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/dynaform/basicUsage.jsf

I have been able to create tree Dynaform objects and send it to the page. But I am having a hard time obtaining the values that the user entered once they clicked submit. I want to be able to get these values in the backbean.

Here is submit button

```
<p:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{dynaFormController.submitForm}"  
                             process="dynaForm" update=":mainForm:dynaFormGroup :mainForm:inputValues"  
                             oncomplete="handleComplete(xhr, status, args)"/>  
<p:commandButton type="reset" value="Reset" style="margin-left: 5px;"/>
```

I know the submit calls this function

```
<h:outputScript id="dynaFormScript" target="body">  
/* <![CDATA[ */ 
    function handleComplete(xhr, status, args) { 
        if(args && args.isValid) { 
            PF('inputValuesWidget').show(); 
        } else { 
            PF('inputValuesWidget').hide(); 
        } 
    } 
/* ]]> */  
</h:outputScript>
```

Then in the bean we have:

```
public String submitForm() {  
        FacesMessage.Severity sev = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getMaximumSeverity();  
        boolean hasErrors = (sev != null && (FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR.compareTo(sev) >= 0));  

        RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();  
        requestContext.addCallbackParam("isValid", !hasErrors);  

        return null;  
    }
```

How would I be able to get either the fields values from the submitted form? 
I have 3 dynaforms that I would like to submit them and be able to get the values in the back bean. Can anyone explain? I tried looking up some tutorials but I didn't find any explaining this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same as plain JSF.

You need a variable in your bean, its getters and setters.
Then, you compare it to the DynaFormControl.

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class DynaFormController implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private DynaFormModel model;  
private BookProperty bookProperty;

public String getBookProperty() {
    return bookProperty;
}
public void setBookProperty(BookProperty bookProperty) {
    this.bookProperty = bookProperty;
}

public String submitForm() {  
    //your code 

    List<DynaFormControl> controls = model.getControls();
    for (DynaFormControl control : controls) {
        if(control.getData() instanceof BookProperty) {
            BookProperty bp = (BookProperty) c.getData();
            //use the object                
        }
    }    

    return null;  
}
```

}